# The data didn't show up in the select list (Apex Oracle)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex

```
select 
    lbi.book_issue_id|| '---'|| (
        select staff_name
        from lms_staff_detail
        where staff_id = (
            select lb.entity_owner_fk
            from lms_borrower lb
            where lb.borrower_id = lbi.borrower_id
        )
    ) as display_value,
    lbi.book_issue_id as return_value
from lms_book_issue lbi
where lbi.borrower_type = :P11_BOOK_RETURN_FORM 
    and book_rt_status = 1 
    and borrower_type = 'FACULTY'
```

im making a select list to display the id in the select list.

i didnt get any error in the code, but when i run it, the select list didnt show up the value or the data.

*to be honest i got this code from copy-paste so i didnt understand this code at all, but the one i copied working fine.

**i got all the table the same as the one i copied

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If query itself runs OK and returns data, then I presume that you didn't put `P11_BOOK_RETURN_FORM` into Select List item's **Parent item(s)** (or **Items to submit**) property (under "Cascading list of values" group of properties).

Comment: the code or query might be ok since when i verified it, it's all green. but i dont know if the code itself returns the data....

tried the cascading list, it doesnt work...

Comment: Well, you should test that query first in e.g. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, Apex SQL Workshop or any other tool you use. Only you have the data, it is pretty much impossible for the rest of us to say anything about it.